# Can this grid layout be achieved more efficiently in React-Native?

Tags: performance, reactjs, react-native, flexbox

I'm seeing very long render times on a component and was wondering if the same could be achieved more efficiently or if it was merely two many elements / too much computation for React Native.

The layout looks like this :

```
<View style={{flex: 1, flexDirection: 'row', alignItems: 'stretch'}}>
    <View style={{width: 250}} />
    <View style={{flex: 1}}>
        <View style={{height: 50}} />
        <View style={{flex: 1}}>
            <Grid columns={15} rows={40} />
        </View>
    </View>
</View>
```

Where the `Grid` component simply renders a grid of `columns` columns containing each `rows` rows of equal width/height using `flex`. Here is [a link](https://gist.github.com/VonD/fa06d7608ec3385b845a) to a full example.

Both on the emulator and a brand new device, with the `dev` flag off, i'm seeing render times between 1.5 and 3.5 seconds, which seems a lot. If I add a button to toggle the left panel, the layout also takes this time to update.

I've tried not using `flex` and precomputing all the values for both states using `Dimensions.get('window')` but the results are similar.

The `systrace`(available [here](https://gist.github.com/VonD/14427c807e68245cf22f)) shows that all the work is done in the UI and Render threads, and it also displays some warnings : `Long View#draw()`.

Am I correct in thinking that at this point it is just too many elements or too complex a layout for React Native ? If so are there any alternative techniques, maybe something similar to the browser's `Canvas`, to draw all these elements ? If not am I doing something wrong ?

Many thanks for your help.

Comment: As an alternative you may use react-native-grid-view.

Comment: @sekogs thanks! I'll give it a try. Ultimately, I'll need something else though, as i will need columns of varying rows size, and as I'll need to prevent scrolling (i think react-native-grid-view uses a ListView). But i'll test the perf and post it here, that will sure be interesting

Comment: after testing react-native-grid-view, the numbers are slightly better but still higher than 1.2s in average

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't need to print anything in the cells, but just need the grid to display, you can render the columns and, then render absolutely-positioned rows over them.

Which means that for an `x * y` grid, you'd have `x + y` `Views` instead of `x * y` : much more efficient!

The performance of a Component's `render` method seems to depend directly on the number of native `Views` involved, which is why the `collapsable` prop exists on Android: it allows to reduce the number of native `Views`, by not rendering the ones that are layout-only.

If you **do** need to render all those `Views`, then there is probably not much to do to speed up the process in react-native as of today, but i would love to be proved wrong!